# Implementing primary key concept using trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to implement the primary key concept (unique+ not null) on one table using a trigger.

So that I can avoid duplicate and null value insertion into the table.

Example here: table `gt1` and column `product`.

I am getting this error:

> ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded

```
CREATE TABLE gt1
(
    PRODUCT VARCHAR2(2), 
    T_DATE DATE,
    YEAR NUMBER(2)
);
```

```
create or replace trigger tg1 before insert on gt1
for each row
declare

msg varchar2(20);
N_prd varchar(2);
cnt number;
begin

N_prd := :new.product;
select count(*) into cnt from gt1 where product=n_prd;

dbms_output.put_line(N_prd || ' ,'|| cnt);

if N_prd is not null or N_prd <>'' 
 then 
   if cnt<>0 then 
      dbms_output.put_line(:new.product||' - Product is already exists');
      else 
      
      insert into gt1 values(:new.product,:new.T_DATE,:new.year);
     
     dbms_output.put_line('insert is success');
    end if;
 else 
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.product||' - is null');

end if;
end;
```

```
INSERT INTO gt1 
VALUES ('P1', sysdate + 1, 23);
```

Comment: Use the trigger only for constraint checks. (I.e. skip the actual insert, it will be done after the trigger has executed.)

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just create the primary key on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a trigger. Use a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint as that is what it is designed for.

```sql
ALTER TABLE gt1 ADD CONSTRAINT gt1__product__pk PRIMARY KEY(product);
```

---

If you really want to use a trigger (don't) then use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger and `RAISE` an exception if the table contains a duplicate value or a `NULL` value else do nothing and let the insert succeed:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg1
  AFTER INSERT ON gt1
DECLARE
  cnt_null PLS_INTEGER;
  cnt_dup  PLS_INTEGER;
  NULL_VALUE EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NULL_VALUE, -1400);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(COUNT(CASE WHEN product IS NULL THEN 1 END)),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 END)
  INTO   cnt_null,
         cnt_dup
  FROM   gt1
  GROUP BY
         product
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0
  OR     COUNT(*) > 1;

  IF cnt_dup > 0 THEN
    RAISE DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX;
  END IF;

  IF cnt_null > 0 THEN
    RAISE NULL_VALUE;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then inserting a duplicate in the same statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO gt1 (product)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Fails with:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_PAKJMILXQHBGVOYNUEEG.TG1", line 18
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_PAKJMILXQHBGVOYNUEEG.TG1'
> ```

and inserting `NULL`:

> ```sql
> INSERT INTO gt1 (product) VALUES (NULL);
> ```

fails with:

> ```
> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_PAKJMILXQHBGVOYNUEEG.TG1", line 22
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_PAKJMILXQHBGVOYNUEEG.TG1'
> ```

And inserting a singular value:

```sql
INSERT INTO gt1 (product) VALUES (1);
```

Succeeds.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMj-uvSf)

Answer (score 0):

Error you got is due to insert trigger performs, because it causes trigger to fire over and over again, until Oracle says *that's enough*. Remove it. Apart from that, simplify code so that you don't use what you don't need (superfluous variable). Then it works - but just for demonstration purposes, as it won't work in real life. Don't do that with a trigger, simply create a primary key.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE gt1
  2  (
  3      PRODUCT VARCHAR2(2),
  4      T_DATE DATE,
  5      YEAR NUMBER(2)
  6  );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace trigger tg1 before insert on gt1
  2    for each row
  3  declare
  4    -- msg varchar2(20); -- you never used it
  5    cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    if :new.product is not null then
  8       select count(*) into cnt from gt1 where product = :new.product;
  9
 10       if cnt > 0 then
 11         raise_application_error(-20000, 'Product ' || :new.product || ' already exists');
 12      else
 13         null;
 14         -- this INSERT fires trigger over and over again
 15         -- insert into gt1 values(:new.product,:new.T_DATE,:new.year);
 16       end if;
 17    else
 18       raise_application_error(-20001, 'Product can not be NULL');
 19    end if;
 20  end;
 21  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: duplicates won't work:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES ('P1', sysdate + 1, 23);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES ('P1', sysdate + 1, 23);
INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES ('P1', sysdate + 1, 23)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Product P1 already exists
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TG1", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TG1'
```

A different product can be inserted:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES ('P2', sysdate + 1, 23);

1 row created.
```

Nulls aren't allowed:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES (null, sysdate + 1, 23);
INSERT INTO gt1 VALUES (null, sysdate + 1, 23)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Product can not be NULL
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TG1", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TG1'


SQL> select * from gt1;

PR T_DATE                 YEAR
-- ---------------- ----------
P1 09.01.2024 21:10         23
P2 09.01.2024 21:10         23
```

However, as long as it works for single row inserts, you'll get mutating table error once you try to insert two or more rows at the same time:

```
SQL> insert into gt1
  2    select 'AB', sysdate, 1 from dual union all
  3    select 'XY', sysdate, 2 from dual;
insert into gt1
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.GT1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TG1", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TG1'


SQL>
```